# Reload changes to a shared data base

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, microservices

I'm using Spring boot, and I have 2 services which share the same data base. each service has its own data source to communicate with the DB.

My problem is when I apply changes via first data source the changes are not being affected or not being reloaded to the second data source.

My question is how can I reload those changes, so whenever i apply changes to one data source they will be reflected by the second\other data source?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You say they share the same data source and then you talk about first and second data source. Can you maybe clarify your question a bit? Also, showing code can help.

Comment: I edit the question. take a look. i meant 2 service share the same DB

Comment: What kind of changes are you making via the datasource?

Comment: I try to do a simple insert via first data source. afterward, I try to read this change on the second service, but it can't find the inserted record.

Comment: Are you able to see the inserted record on the database? Do you have any kind of caching setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to simply share the DB between the two services using Spring Data Rest.